# How to retrieve Google Analytic cookies in Java/ using Firebug?

Tags: java, cookies, https, firebug

I've been trying to capture https traffic in firefox using firebug during an website login and my browser sends some Google Analytic Cookies (such as __utma, __utmb) without receiving any of them first.

My goal is to implement some of the headers in java so I need also the cookies. I can see most of them but none of those GA cookies.

So my question is: how can I fetch those cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

All cookies set for the current page are listed within Firebug's [*Cookies* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Cookies_Panel), also the Google Analytics ones.

The Google Analytics cookies are set via JavaScript within the ga.js file. For the Firebug website for example they look like this:
[image: Cookies on getfirebug.com]

So you can set them in your Java program like any other cookie.